# PSQL If Null order by Username

Tags: psql

Lets say I have the following table:

```
 username | surname | firstname |  type   | mark | username | group_id 
----------+---------+-----------+---------+------+----------+----------
 s68      | sln68   | sfn68     | student |   37 | s68      |     1992
 s67      | sln67   | sfn67     | student |   37 | s67      |     1992
 s84      | sln84   | sfn84     | student |   37 | s84      |     1992
 s70      | sln70   | sfn70     | student |   37 | s70      |     1992
 s63      | sln63   | sfn63     | student |   37 | s63      |     1992
 s1       | sln1    | sfn1      | student |   12 | s1       |     2000
 s2       | sln2    | sfn2      | student |   12 | s2       |     2000
 s49      | sln47   | sfn47     | student |      |          |         
 s48      | sln48   | sfn48     | student |      |          |         
 s47      | sln49   | sfn49     | student |      |          |         
 s50      | sln50   | sfn50     | student |      |          |         
 s52      | sln51   | sfn51     | student |      |          |         
 s51      | sln52   | sfn52     | student |      |          |
```

I have sorted the `rows` based on the `mark` column in desc order. The rows where `mark` is null is put at the end of the table. But for the rows with `mark = null` I want to sort by the `username` in `ASC`. How do I do this?

I have tried something like this `order by case when mark is null then username asc else...` but that doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Order By mark desc nulls last, username asc;
```